# php syntax - using 'or' and '&&' in statement

Tags: php, syntax

This is for a text field password input. 
Here is my code:

`$vaar` is what is entered into that field.

`if(($vaar !='pass01' or 'pass02') &&  (!empty($vaar))) {`

I can't figure out the correct syntax. I've tried `||`, `or`, `xor`.
I've also tried placing `'pass01'` and `'pass02'` in their own `( )`'s.

What I want it to do is this:

If `$vaar` isn't `'pass01'` or `'pass02'` and `$vaar` is not empty then do this:

just a syntax error, but I can't figure it out!

Comment: Besides the good answers below, I want to add something general: PHP checks the expressions from left to right, if one fails completely (without an alternative expression evaluateing `true` by `OR`) it won't check the following anymore

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're looking for:

```
if( !empty($vaar) && ($vaar != 'pass01' && $vaar != 'pass02')) {
```

Note that I've put the `empty()` check first, which will short-circuit the evaluation should `$vaar` in fact be empty.

**Edit:** To better reflect the OP's wording (and logic), this is identical to the following, because of [Demorgan's law.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws)):

```
if( !empty($vaar) && !($vaar == 'pass01' || $vaar == 'pass02')) {
```

Reads: *If `$vaar` is not empty and `$vaar` is not `pass01` or `pass02`*

Comment: `x != y || x != z` for differing `y` and `z` always returns true. -1

Comment: @Kolink - You're absolutely right, I had originally written it with `&&` and then changed it from reading the OP, but the correct logic expression is with `&&`. Thanks.

Comment: @Downvoters - Care to explain? I would like to improve my answer if it is inadequate.

Comment: @nickb I'm getting downvoted too but I think your answer is adequate.

Comment: both of you two ended up with the same answer, and it works. Points go here b/c he posted the empty() in the beginning, and also for the DeMorgan's law reference :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
if(($vaar !== 'pass01' and $vaar !== 'pass02') and (!empty($vaar))) {
   // ...
}
```

Alternatively:

```
if(($vaar !== 'pass01' && $vaar !== 'pass02') && (!empty($vaar))) {
   // ...
}
```

What you actually mean is:

If `$vaar` is not equal to "pass01" AND `$vaar` is not equal to "pass02" AND `$vaar` is not empty, then ...

Note that I have kept your original parentheses in there, but since they are all AND, you may remove them, like this:

```
if(!empty($vaar) && $vaar !== 'pass01' && $vaar !== 'pass02') {
   // ...
}
```

Here, I have also moved the `empty` language construct to the beginning of the conditional, as if the variable is empty then the conditional will evaluate the false immediately, preventing an `E_NOTICE` error for `Undefined variable $vaar` if the variable is undefined.

Comment: Suggest moving the `empty` check first, since that will short-circut the other two conditions (as it is more broad) but will also prevent notices in case of an undefined variable.

Comment: @Kolink Good idea, answer now improved.